# Connecting to slack

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm testing slack and trying to send message from the sever to one of the users. I created a new app and keep getting an error:

```
{
    'ok': False,
    'error': 'invalid_auth',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length': '55',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Date': 'Thu, 08 Nov 2018 09:54:56 GMT',
        'Server': 'Apache',
        'X-Slack-Exp': '1',
        'X-Slack-Backend': 'h',
        'x-slack-router': 'p',
        'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer',
        'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
        preload ', '
        X - Slack - Req - Id ': '
        3 c53b943 - bebb - 47 ca - ada0 - be13e4988bdb ',
        'X-XSS-Protection': '0',
        'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
        'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
        'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'X-Via': 'haproxy-www-bw0h',
        'X-Cache': 'Miss from cloudfront',
        'Via': '1.1
        a6c2f92bd73abb61e78964fa0cb27509.cloudfront.net(CloudFront)
        ',
        'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'lSiGiWlZ713eBxZpQwQR2TJ6ziYRYiykGos3eKPs4EfGOHoUBaQWjA=='
    }
}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient

slack_client_id = 'I"ll not show you'
slack_client_secret = 'I"ll show it either :-) '

sc = SlackClient(client_id=slack_client_id, client_secret=slack_client_secret)

chan = sc.api_call(   "channels.list",   exclude_archived=1 )
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the SlackClient API correctly.

You have to provide a [Slack token](https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types), not the "client ID" and "client secret" for the API call.

Example:

```
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient

sc = SlackClient("xoxb-TOKEN")

chan = sc.api_call(   "channels.list",   exclude_archived=1 )
```

The "client ID" and "client secret" is used to install your app to a workspace using [Oauth 2.0](https://slackapi.github.io/python-slackclient/auth.html#the-oauth-flow). This will create a token for your app, which you can then use to call the API. Of course you have to install you app once only.

Note that if you are working with your own Slack workspace you can also install you app directly and get the token in the management screen of your Slack app.

See also the [documentation](https://slackapi.github.io/python-slackclient/) of the [SlackClient](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) for more examples on how to use it correctly.